# rectifying KML file to match GoogleEarth imagery

Tags: qgis, kml, georeferencing

Ubuntu 14.04, QGIS 2.12:

In QGIS I have a polygon (33 segments) which I have successfully exported to GoogleEarth as a KML file.
Due to rectification of GE's image, the polygon doesn't quite line up, of course.

The one certain point I can line up in both mappings requires a shift of KML data 5 metres westward.
So I have carefully edited the KML file to reduce the Easting of every point by 0.00004° .
And it works, but it is very laborious and error-prone, so I'm thinking there must be a better way.

Really I want to do a rectification on the polygon's coordinates, to stretch/squeeze/rotate to match what Google has done to their image.

I can certainly write a PHP-CLI script to manipulate the file, but is there a better way, or has someone this before?

Answer (score 1):

There are some plugins that allow georeferencing of vector data:

- Vector Bender (experimental)
- vectorgeoref (experimental)
- Affine Transformations

You have to allow experimental plugins to be listed in the `Settings` tab of the Plugin Manager to get the first two.

Creating a custom CRS with a false Easting of 5 meters would be another option, if your data is in a projected CRS. You have to reproject to WGS84 in order to export the data to KML.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Trouble is I don't know what any of them means.  I have written the PHP script to do a simple move of the coordinates, including a bunch of polygons - http://davekimble.org.au/adjust.kml.php.txt   More complex versions by changing function adjust().